# SQL server: Get week number of month with saturday as first day of week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a sql script to calculate the week number of month with saturday as the first day of the week.

**Example:**

```
2017-04-01 : Week 1
2017-04-02 : Week 1
(.................)
2017-04-08 : Week 2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think it's all that you need:

```
set datefirst 6

declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '2017-03-04'

select datepart(wk, @dt) - datepart(wk,dateadd(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0, @dt), 0)) + 1 as weekOfMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql) with `DATEADD`. Setting `DATEFIRST` to the value `6` represents Saturday.

Try this (replace `yourDate` with your `datetime` column):

```
SET DATEFIRST 6
select datediff(week, dateadd(month, 0, yourDate), yourDate) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Douek for your answer, but this syntax display this error msg to me: "The data type datetime argument is invalid for second argument of the dateadd function."

Comment: @Koby Douek, swap yourDate and 0 in dateadd()

Comment: @MustaphaAitFadel Please see updated answer

Comment: @KobyDouek Please check your answer on dates 1st of march and 4st of march, as I understand this question, 4st of march must by the first day of the second week in this month.

Comment: @MustaphaAitFadel I tested it now - adding `SET DATEFIRST 6` works - see updated answer

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко See updated answer.

Comment: @KobyDouek for '2017-03-04' your query return 0. Do you have another result?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко I was missing the `+ 1`

Comment: @KobyDouek I want to say, that first day of the week should be a Saturday, that mean for example, '2017-03-03' belong to 1st week, but '2017-03-04' to 2nd week.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query

```
DECLARE @currentdate date = '2017-04-01'
select floor((datepart(day,@currentdate) - 1)/7) + 1 AS WeekOfMonth

--- @currentdate date = '2017-04-01' -- return 1
--- @currentdate date = '2017-04-07' -- return 1
--- @currentdate date = '2017-04-08' -- return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of below query :

```
 SELECT 'Week '+ CAST(FLOOR((datepart(day,@YourDate) - 1)/7) + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) Currentweek
```